# Which version of coreclr?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, coreclr

In the .NET CLI I can use the switch `--version` to get the version of CLI. Is there a similar way to get the version of the `coreclr` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version of the coreclr is in our application's project.json. `dnvm list -detailed` (from the previous toolchain) shows us runtime info which is completely irrelevant to the `dotnet` toolchain.

```
> dnvm list -detailed
Active Version         Runtime Architect OperatingSystem Alias   Location
------ -------         ------- --------- --------------- -----   --------
       1.0.0-rc2-16595 coreclr x64       win                     C:\Users\me\.dnx\runtimes 
  *    1.0.0-rc2-20221 clr     x86       win             default C:\Users\me\.dnx\runtimes
```

We can find the equivalent `dotnet` relevant information:

- **Version and Runtime** are in project.json's `frameworks` section (e.g. netcoreapp1.0, net451).
- **Architecture and Operating System** are in project.json's `runtimes` section (e.g. win7-x64).
- **Location** is our NuGet global-packages folder (`nuget locals all -list`) after restore and our project's `bin` after build.
- **Alias and Active** are obsolete.

["There's no dnvm replacement"](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AnUpdateOnASPNETCore10RC2.aspx) for the .NET CLI and no command to "get the version of the coreclr." That is because the runtime is now fully specified in our project.json and installed with the `dotnet restore` command.

With the `dnu/dnx/dnvm` toolchain, we installed the runtime independently from our application and its dependencies.

1. We used `dnvm install|upgrade|use` to download and use a runtime; `dnvm` did not consult project.json.
2. We used `dnu restore` to download application specific dependencies; `dnu` did consult project.json.

With the `dotnet` toolchain the `restore` operation combines those two steps. It consults our project.json and downloads both the runtime and the dependencies.

`dnvm` does not interact with the `dotnet` toolchain. In fact, we can delete the `~/.dnx` directory and `dotnet` will build our project.

Comment: I was under the impression that _dnvm_ is deprecated and _dotnet_ replaces the entire dnu, dnx, dnvm toolchain, but I guess it does not really matter in this case, at least not until it goes away.

Comment: @Marcus "There's no dnvm replacement." http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AnUpdateOnASPNETCore10RC2.aspx

Answer (score 5):

No more `dnvm`.

The version of coreclr is determined in your `project.json` file.

Also there is a shared runtime when you install dotnet cli. You can find it in dotnet cli folder.

If your applicaiton have not specified any runtime in `project.json` then you app is portable and will run using shared runtime. You can specify multiple runtimes and your application binaries will be compiled for all this runtimes separately.

**UPDATED**:

Adding link to [.NET Platform Standard](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md) documentation describing new way to design API in .NET

Link to David Fowl's GitHub [repository](https://github.com/davidfowl/NetStandard) describing .NET Platform Standard

Here is an example where runtimes are specified

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "warningsAsErrors": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true,
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
       ...
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "net451": {
      "dependencies": {
        ....
      }
    },
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ],
      "dependencies": {
        "NETStandard.Library": "1.5.0-rc2-24018",
        "Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel": "1.0.0-rc2-002416"
      }
    }
  },
  "content": [
    "config.json"
  ],
  "runtimes": {
    "win7-x64": {},
    "win7-x86": {},
    "osx.10.11-x64": {},
    "ubuntu.14.04-x64": {},
    "centos.7-x64": {},
    "rhel.7.2-x64": {},
    "debian.8.2-x64": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: @ShaunLuttin there are no more locally installed runtimes which were maintained via `dnvm`. All your runtimes are managed within your application using `project.json`

Answer (score 2):

<sup>The existing answers probably have all the information, but that's in part obscured by legacy information, so let me attempt a **pragmatic summary as of .NET Core v2.0 beta**.</sup>

- While there ***is* a globally active *SDK* version**, as reported by `dotnet --version`<sup>[1]</sup>
  ,
- there's ***no* globally active *runtime* (CoreCLR) version** - runtimes are installed side-by-side, and ***each project* determines which runtime it targets**, by way of its `*.csproj` file.

To **list all *installed* CoreCLR versions**:

- In **`bash`**:

  - `ls -1 "$(dirname "$(which dotnet)")/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App"`
- In **PowerShell Core** (both Windows and Unix):

  - `(Get-ChildItem "$((Get-Command -Type Application dotnet).source)/../shared/Microsoft.NETCore.app").Name`

To **inspect *a given project's* target CoreCLR:** (run the commands in the project root folder):

- In **`bash`**:

  - `awk -F '</?RuntimeFrameworkVersion>' 'NF>1 {print $2}' *.csproj`
- In **PowerShell Core** (both Windows and Unix):

  - `([xml] (Get-Content -Raw *.csproj)).Project.PropertyGroup.RuntimeFrameworkVersion`

For a **PowerShell Core script that wraps this functionality and more**, see [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/mklement0/e4d480fe0fbad0c7cc85a8670ac04be7) of mine.

---

<sup>[1] Optionally, on a per-project basis, you can override the globally active SDK version by placing a `global.json` file in the project folder - see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/global-json).

Also note that just running `dotnet` *without parameters* or running `dotnet --version` *without the SDK installed* will show text that reflects the shared *host* ("driver") version - this obscure and confusing behavior is being discussed on GitHub [here](https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup/issues/1593).</sup>